# MVC5: ProductsApiController -> remove Api from route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, attributes, routes

I have named my API controllers using 'ApiController' as the postfix to avoid collision with the MVC controllers that serve up my views.

The problem is my URLs all look like this now: server/api/ProductsApi/5 which offends my sense of style. I would like it to be /api/Products/5

Is the only way to solve this by putting a RoutePrefix("api/Products") on class, then decorate every action?

Thanks,
~Shea M.

Comment: Why not put the ApiControllers in a different namespace? Then it doesn't matter if you have an ApiController and a Mvc Controller named the same.

Comment: They are in a different namespace. I have them in a sub folder/namespace called 'Api'. With MVC controllers it ignores namespace, so I thought it might cause conflicts.

Comment: Darrel's suggestion seems to work fine.

Comment: Web API ignores namespace too, but the web api routing looks for classes derived from ApiController and MVC looks for controllers derived from Controller. And because your routes don't overlap because of the `api` there is no conflict.

Comment: " web api routing looks for classes derived from ApiController " I was missing this peice of the puzzle. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong.  It looks for classes that implement IHttpController.  ApiController implements that interface.